# Tower of Hanoi Problem: Two Dimensions

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm reading Knuths *Concrete Mathematics* and trying to solve my own questions as I read through the book. Right now, I want to solve a variant of the tower of Hanoi problem - solving for minimum number of moves `T(n)` to shift `n` disks from one tower to another given `z` towers.

This becomes a recurrence relation on two variables - so simply looking for `T(n)` with `z=3`wont help. I need a more powerful methodology with which to approach this problem.

I'm thinking you can represent towers as binary numbers of length `n` and then think about the situation as a finite state automaton. You move disks with bit shifts and there must be exactly `n`after every operation.

Any ideas how to approach this multidimensional recurrence relation?

Comment: It seems from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond) that the optimal solution is an open problem -- are you talking about the recurrence relation for the "presumed-optimal" Frame-Stewart algorithm? Or if not, which recurrence relation do you mean?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Wikipedia article reports that Frame-Stewart is proved optimal for four towers.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Yes, but I understood $z$ to be arbitrary here.

Comment: Z is meant to be arbitrary. I didn't anticipate this happening – my asking an as of yet unanswered question in mathematics. I'll give myself a pat on the back for my effort and return to this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

See this paper for some insight into the question: https://www2.bc.edu/~grigsbyj/Rand_Final.pdf.

> It seems from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#With_four_pegs_and_beyond) that the optimal solution is an open problem -- are you talking about the recurrence relation for the "presumed-optimal" Frame-Stewart algorithm? – joriki